# Using Dotnet with NSIS fails on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, dll, gdi+, nsis

I'm using an unmanaged C# dll (using DllExport and dotnet framework 4.0) to add UI capabilities to an NSIS installer, but basic controls constructors throw a `font '?' cannot be found.` exception on windows 7. Code example:

```
[DllExport]
public static void CreateRichTextBox()
{
    try
    {
        RichTextBox myRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
        MessageBox.Show("RichTextBox created on windows 10");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RichTextBox contractor failed on windows 7 with " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

So after some digging, I got to the conclusion that this happeneds because of a function used by NSIS that messes internal paths for the Dotnet: [SetDefaultDllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories).

The function was added for security reasons [explaind by the NSIS team](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/bugs/1125/):

> Using SetDefaultDllDirectories we can globally change the behavior
> of LoadLibraryEx so that it only looks into the System32 folder and into any
> directories explicitly added with AddDllDirectories.

I only guess that this is a Gdiplus bug that was eventually solved but I still wonder if someone knows of a workaround to make it work on windows 7?

Comment: You first link is for the loader.  So I'm thinking the issue is with the build options for 32 bit vs 64 bit.  You are using Net 4.0 which is 32 bit.  So I'm thinking the changes you added are using 64 bit.  So make sure you are not using any WoW64 folders.  Windows 7 first release was 32 bit mode and then later went to 64 bit mode.  I think you should have the 64 version of Windows 7 like most people.  I can't reach the second linked.  Being blocked.  It suspect for security reason the new code is using an encryption mode that is not supported in Net 4.0.

Comment: It looks like NSIS updates is trying to use TLS 1.2.  TLS 1.2 is not supported with Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The [public Microsoft bug report](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001000020im_/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2281687/setdefaultdlldirectories-results-in-exception-during-opening-a-winform-on-win7) claims the bug is in Windows (GDI+) and not technically a .NET specific issue.

Unfortunately MSDN says this about SetDefaultDllDirectories:

> **It is not possible to revert to the standard DLL search path** or remove any directory specified with SetDefaultDllDirectories from the search path. ...

This means the only workaround is to not call the function in the first place. The only way to do that in NSIS is to use a hex-editor and modify the stubs in `NSIS\Stubs`. Search for `SetDefaultDllDirectories` in the relevant stub and change it to something like `SetDefaultxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (replace as many characters as you want but the length has to stay the same!).

This of course means that your installer will be somewhat vulnerable to malicious .DLL planting attacks. You can try to restore the functionality somewhat with:

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
${If} ${AtLeastWin8}
  System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetDefaultDllDirectories(i 0x800|0x400)'
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

but the protection is slightly less effective this way and does nothing on Windows 7.